# Bloom filter with bitwise operations in python

Tags: python, bloom-filter

Consider the following Python implemetation for the [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter):

```
class BloomFilter(object):
    """A simple bloom filter for lots of int/str"""

    def __init__(self, array_size=(1 * 1024), hashes=13):
        """Initializes a BloomFilter() object:
            Expects:
                array_size (in bytes): 4 * 1024 for a 4KB filter
                hashes (int): for the number of hashes to perform"""

        self.filter = bytearray(array_size)     # The filter itself
        self.bitcount = array_size * 8          # Bits in the filter
        self.hashes = hashes                    # The number of hashes to use

    def _hash(self, value):
        """Creates a hash of an int and yields a generator of hash functions
        Expects:
            value: int()
        Yields:
            generator of ints()"""

        # Build an int() around the sha256 digest of int() -> value
        value = value.__str__() # Comment out line if you're filtering strings()
        digest = int(sha256(value).hexdigest(), 16)
        for _ in range(self.hashes):
            yield digest & (self.bitcount - 1)
            digest >>= (256 / self.hashes)

    def add(self, value):
        """Bitwise OR to add value(s) into the self.filter
        Expects:
            value: generator of digest ints()
        """
        for digest in self._hash(value):
            self.filter[(digest / 8)] |= (2 ** (digest % 8))


    def query(self, value):
        """Bitwise AND to query values in self.filter
        Expects:
            value: value to check filter against (assumed int())"""
        return all(self.filter[(digest / 8)] & (2 ** (digest % 8)) 
            for digest in self._hash(value))
```

A simple use of this bloom filter would be:

```
bf = BloomFilter()

bf.add(30000)
bf.add(1230213)
bf.add(1)

print("Filter size {0} bytes").format(bf.filter.__sizeof__())
print bf.query(1) # True
print bf.query(1230213) # True
print bf.query(12) # False
```

Can you explain **in detail** how the hash functions are used? For example in the line:

```
self.filter[(digest / 8)] |= (2 ** (digest % 8))
```

it seems that the code is using `OR` and `AND` operations to write to the filter using the hash functions created using `self._hash` but I cannot understand how this bitwise operation works when adding and querying values to/from the filter.

- Why the `2**(digest %8)`?
- Why the use of `OR` to write to the filter and `AND` to query?